# Pool memory and std::forward_list

Tags: c++, c++11, boost, forward-list

I would create a memory pool for the node of a C++11 `forward_list`.

Is it possible use the BOOST pool memory with `std::forward_list`?

Answer (score 2):

[This stack-overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703643/can-i-assume-allocators-dont-hold-their-memory-pool-directly-and-can-therefore/11703840#11703840) provides source code for a C++11-conforming pool allocator that will work with any C++11-conforming container, including `std::forward_list`.

Comment: Allocator for elements. I think question is not about it.

Comment: @ForEveR: A `rebind`'d allocator is used for the nodes.