# Custom allocator in std::vector

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, allocator

Is it possible to use custom allocator for `std::vector` internal allocations? If yes, how?

Comment: template < class T, **class Allocator = allocator<T>** > class vector;

Comment: @LuchianGrigore And how to use that?

Comment: First google link - http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/memory/myalloc1.cpp.html and http://www.josuttis.com/libbook/memory/myalloc.hpp.html

Comment: See this recent answer by Howard Hinnant: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11703840/819272

Comment: What do you mean by "internal allocations"? What aspect of the vector's allocator concept is unclear?

Comment: @KerrekSB If I am not mistaken, `vector` calls `new` / `delete` internally when the size changes. Those (de)allocations were meant by the word 'internal'.

Comment: @James: No. `vector` calls `alloc.allocate()` and `alloc.deallocate()` when the size changes.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You basically have to implement your allocator type to conform to the [*Allocator concept*](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).

The linked page lists all requirements of that type, but the core functionality is implemented in the `allocate` member function.

Comment: could you give an example

Comment: @serup Click on the link, it has tons of examples.

Comment: This is exactly the reason why link only answers are *bad*! The page doesn't exist anymore. Pointing towards examples in the broken link is even worse.

Comment: At least I updated the link. The new page is referenced, as cppreference is a wiki. But your point is taken.

Comment: Here is a [running example](https://godbolt.org/z/7fnj1rGr9) derived from the [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/named_req/Allocator).